# How to get Latest commit on github on website

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get a thing on my website that shows the latest commit on GitHub.
I have seen this on many websites. For example[This is one on the materealizecss.com website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQa0A.png)

How could I make one of these on my website using just js and HTML (JS frameworks accepted if needed)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check github API. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit for example.

Comment: I am not good with js. I would like to be helped some more with direct code. I know most people won't do that but it can help me better I am a noob at js.

I would like to at least be able to know how to connect to the API.

Thanks for letting me know @Smollet777 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try a widget. like this for example: https://github.com/TylerLH/github-latest-commits-widget

Comment: Thanks!
I have looked all over github to find one but never found one.
I will use this but change up some things like the css due to it being outdated and such. Thanks Again!

Comment: glad it helped :)